# Initialize modify interaction so it can only delete vertices, OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to initialize modify interaction in the way that the user can only delete vertices. I want to disable the other two functionalities which interaction offers like moving and adding new ones. Does anyone have some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `altKeyOnly` condition to the Modify interaction:

```
import { altKeyOnly } from "ol/events/condition";
import { Modify } from "ol/interaction";

const features = ...;   // get modifying features

const modify = new Modify({
    features: features,
    condition: altKeyOnly,
    ...
});

...
```

Comment: I am working with OpenLayers 3 https://geoadmin.github.io/ol3/apidoc/ol.interaction.Modify.html, there isn't condition property

Comment: It works anyway, this is how my options looks like , but now my deleteCondition is not working , {
                    features : select.getFeatures(),
                    deleteCondition : ol.events.condition.click,
                    condition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly,
                }